# passing flash parameters

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3

i have a flash button and i want to pass the button link (after click) as parameter. what is the best way to do it?

Comment: to whom? some code might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters along to Flash using [flashvars](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html).

Suppose you want to pass the URL of the website to navigate to when the user clicks a button, you can add the following parameter to your Flash `<OBJECT>` HTML tag:

```
<param name="url" value="http://www.helloworld.com" />
```

In ActionScript, you can read this flashvar using this piece of code:

```
var flashVars:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
var url:String = "http://www.backupurl.com";

if (flashVars.url != undefined) {
    url = flashVars.url;
}
```

(Source example borrowed from [this blog article](http://www.align.sk/2010/02/flashvars-in-actionscript-3-0/))

Comment: this is what i was looking for.
how do i read it inside the flash?

Answer (score 0):

this is how it's done in AS3:
    root.loaderInfo.parameters[ "name of param you want to read" ];